# How to have terminator open tabs on tailing (less +F) log files on remote machines

Tags: command-line, bash, terminator

I would like to develop a terminator layout that opens 4 tabs, having 3 of them showing log files on remote machines in tailing mode (`less +F <logfile>`) and the last one monitoring the content of a folder with [command watch](https://ss64.com/bash/watch.html).

To better explain, this is what I would do manually as user to achieve what I want:

First, I would manually split terminator window into 4 tabs displayed as 2x2: 1 vertical split, 1 horizontal split

```
 1  |  2
----------
 3  |  4
```

Then in each tab I would run the following commands:

### tab 1

```
ssh user_P@remote_machine_ip
sudo -i -u user_O
less +F /path/to/log1/log1.log
```

### tab 2

```
ssh user_P@remote_machine_ip
sudo -i -u user_O
less +F /path/to/log2/log2.log
```

### tab 3

```
ssh user_P@remote_machine_ip
sudo -i -u user_O
sudo less +F /path/to/log3/log3.log
```

### tab 4

```
ssh user_P@remote_machine_ip
sudo -i -u user_O
watch -n 1 ls /home/user_O/my_folder/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1 - create and save the desired tabs disposition layout

[This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168445/466197) explains well how to do it.

start by opening terminator configuration file by running

`xdg-open /home/your_local_user/.config/terminator/config`

### 2 - Write the commands to run for each tab

Under the section `[[your-custom-layout-name]]` You have to add a key `command = ...` under each text snippet like

```
 [[[terminal<number>]]]
       type = Terminal
```

The content of each key `command` of your tab should be:

**tab 1**

```
command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O less +F /path/to/log1/log1.log
```

**tab 2**

```
command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O sudo less +F /path/to/log2/log2.log
```

**tab 3**

```
command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O less +F /path/to/log1/log1.log
```

**tab 4**

```
command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O watch -n 1 ls /home/user_O/my_folder/
```

In the end your layout should look like this:

```
[global_config]
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadBugURLHandler, LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, TerminalShot, SelectAll
  case_sensitive = False
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[window0]]]
      type = Window
      parent = ""
    [[[child1]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      profile = default
  [[your-custom-layout-name]]
    [[[child0]]]
      type = Window
      parent = ""
      order = 0
      position = 0:0
      maximised = True
      fullscreen = False
      size = 1920, 773
      title = user_O@remote_machine_alias
      last_active_term = 99c695d1-9a3e-43bb-a424-55ed77e9e4e8
      last_active_window = False
    [[[child1]]]
      type = HPaned
      parent = child0
      order = 0
      position = 958
      ratio = 0.5002610966057441
    [[[child2]]]
      type = VPaned
      parent = child1
      order = 0
      position = 385
      ratio = 0.5013020833333334
    [[[terminal3]]]
      type = Terminal
      title = tab 1
      command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O less +F /path/to/log1/log1.log
      parent = child2
      order = 0
      profile = default
      uuid = 6cebd0a2-f543-41e9-8cb4-dcfad9feb41c
    [[[terminal4]]]
      type = Terminal
      title = tab 3
      command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O less +F /path/to/log3/log3.log
      parent = child2
      order = 1
      profile = default
      uuid = d328e8b6-8822-4880-b9d6-97ca87cae185
    [[[child5]]]
      type = VPaned
      parent = child1
      order = 1
      position = 385
      ratio = 0.5013020833333334
    [[[terminal6]]]
      type = Terminal
      title = tab 2
      command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O sudo less +F /path/to/log2/log2.log
      parent = child5
      order = 0
      profile = default
      uuid = 99c695d1-9a3e-43bb-a424-55ed77e9e4e8
    [[[terminal7]]]
      type = Terminal
      title = tab 4
      command = ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 user_P@remote_machine_ip sudo -i -u user_O watch -n 1 ls /home/user_O/my_folder/
      parent = child5
      order = 1
      profile = default
      uuid = 777a548f-868b-4a80-81d7-5cf973de5cad
[plugins]
```

In the end, open terminator with your custom layour from your terminal

```
terminator -l your-custom-layout-name
```

**Warning**:

Every tab in less/watch must be stopped with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before being closed from terminator UI, otherwise the less/watch processes will continue in background mode, draining your CPU.